# gerrit prolog submit rule condition check

Tags: prolog, gerrit

We are using gerrit 2.11 to add manager-approval label if inserted code over defined threshold.  the prolog rules.pl as below.

I can remove "Manager-Approval" using line 7 and commented line 8; but if commented line7 and active line 8, "Manager-Approval" is always there.

If I am going to use the following line to replace line 8, Manager-Approval is also there, does that mean `commit_stats()` always return `true`, and line 8 will not run `remove_verified()` call?

We are new in prolog, Any hell will be greatly appreciated.

remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- inserted = 10, inserted > 5, remove_verified(T, R), !.

```
submit_rule(S) :-
       gerrit:default_submit(X),
       X =.. [submit | Ls],
       remove_verified(Ls, R),
       S =.. [submit | R].

remove_verified([], []).
%remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- remove_verified(T, R), !.
remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- gerrit:commit_stats(_, inserted, _), inserted > 5, remove_verified(T, R), !.
remove_verified([H|T], [H|R]) :- remove_verified(T, R).
```

Comment: Variables in Prolog must be capitalized. `submit` and `inserted` are atoms, not variables, which doesn't look right to me (as a non-user of Gerritt).

Comment: Sorry, `submit` is probably right because you're constructing something with univ. But `inserted` still looks wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. you are right, insert should be Insert, this rule works after changing insert to Insert.

Answer (score 1):

for later reference, following submit rules works well.

- In Prolog, variable must start with capital character*

---

```
submit_rule(S) :-
       gerrit:default_submit(X),
       X =.. [submit | Ls],
       remove_verified(Ls, R),
       S =.. [submit | R].

remove_verified([], []).
%remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- remove_verified(T, R), !.
remove_verified([label('Manager-Approval', _) | T], R) :- gerrit:commit_stats(_, Inserted, _), Inserted > 5, remove_verified(T, R), !.
remove_verified([H|T], [H|R]) :- remove_verified(T, R).
```